# Using rbind to prepare data for regression

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have 2 datasets that I want to use to do a regression on. prep_data is a list of items each with a value for 24 hours:

```
    device_id  h     city   mean_t
1      2C7970 00 Auckland 18.60507
2      2C7970 01 Auckland 18.56266
3      2C7970 02 Auckland 18.46109
4      2C7970 03 Auckland 18.38914
5      2C7970 04 Auckland 18.29095
6      2C7970 05 Auckland 18.28618
7      2C7970 06 Auckland 18.28742
8      2C7970 07 Auckland 18.28725
9      2C7970 08 Auckland 18.34685
10     2C7970 09 Auckland 18.52965
11     2C7970 10 Auckland 18.78257
12     2C7970 11 Auckland 19.05493
13     2C7970 12 Auckland 19.13627
14     2C7970 13 Auckland 19.30245
15     2C7970 14 Auckland 19.49134
16     2C7970 15 Auckland 19.49379
17     2C7970 16 Auckland 19.42745
18     2C7970 17 Auckland 19.30474
19     2C7970 18 Auckland 19.25752
20     2C7970 19 Auckland 19.15033
21     2C7970 20 Auckland 19.02484
22     2C7970 21 Auckland 18.88421
23     2C7970 22 Auckland 18.79243
24     2C7970 23 Auckland 18.70263
25     2C797D 00 Auckland 16.35536
26     2C797D 01 Auckland 16.13241
27     2C797D 02 Auckland 15.91293
28     2C797D 03 Auckland 15.64948
29     2C797D 04 Auckland 15.34483
30     2C797D 05 Auckland 15.19293
31     2C797D 06 Auckland 15.16948
32     2C797D 07 Auckland 15.23397
33     2C797D 08 Auckland 15.69017
34     2C797D 09 Auckland 16.18345
35     2C797D 10 Auckland 16.60586
36     2C797D 11 Auckland 16.80259
37     2C797D 12 Auckland 16.92842
38     2C797D 13 Auckland 17.31712
39     2C797D 14 Auckland 17.57376
40     2C797D 15 Auckland 17.63069
41     2C797D 16 Auckland 17.72552
42     2C797D 17 Auckland 17.69621
43     2C797D 18 Auckland 17.56276
44     2C797D 19 Auckland 17.45534
45     2C797D 20 Auckland 17.29776
46     2C797D 21 Auckland 17.07296
47     2C797D 22 Auckland 16.83681
48     2C797D 23 Auckland 16.65069
49     2C7985 00 Auckland 17.29410
50     2C7985 01 Auckland 16.88867
51     2C7985 02 Auckland 16.71007
52     2C7985 03 Auckland 16.54133
53     2C7985 04 Auckland 16.27081
54     2C7985 05 Auckland 16.02517
55     2C7985 06 Auckland 15.98891
56     2C7985 07 Auckland 15.93858
57     2C7985 08 Auckland 15.87868
58     2C7985 09 Auckland 15.91705
59     2C7985 10 Auckland 16.57119
60     2C7985 11 Auckland 17.14488
61     2C7985 12 Auckland 17.53762
62     2C7985 13 Auckland 18.23825
63     2C7985 14 Auckland 18.69074
64     2C7985 15 Auckland 18.90296
65     2C7985 16 Auckland 19.11993
66     2C7985 17 Auckland 19.10441
67     2C7985 18 Auckland 18.76062
68     2C7985 19 Auckland 18.52761
69     2C7985 20 Auckland 18.33885
70     2C7985 21 Auckland 17.98059
71     2C7985 22 Auckland 17.66859
72     2C7985 23 Auckland 17.58604
73     2C7A55 00 Auckland 17.82138
74     2C7A55 01 Auckland 17.67769
75     2C7A55 02 Auckland 17.43013
76     2C7A55 03 Auckland 17.28240
77     2C7A55 04 Auckland 17.13849
78     2C7A55 05 Auckland 16.93355
79     2C7A55 06 Auckland 16.71875
80     2C7A55 07 Auckland 16.63651
81     2C7A55 08 Auckland 16.58069
82     2C7A55 09 Auckland 16.60646
83     2C7A55 10 Auckland 16.70066
84     2C7A55 11 Auckland 16.82496
85     2C7A55 12 Auckland 17.16405
86     2C7A55 13 Auckland 17.52680
87     2C7A55 14 Auckland 17.78660
88     2C7A55 15 Auckland 18.03415
89     2C7A55 16 Auckland 18.26683
90     2C7A55 17 Auckland 18.39262
91     2C7A55 18 Auckland 18.41612
92     2C7A55 19 Auckland 18.39901
93     2C7A55 20 Auckland 18.35181
94     2C7A55 21 Auckland 18.25581
95     2C7A55 22 Auckland 18.11842
96     2C7A55 23 Auckland 17.94852
```

And the table to bind looks like this:

```
   city_name  h outdoor_hum outdoor_temp
1   Auckland 00    87.00000     11.62608
2   Auckland 01    86.87500     11.52487
3   Auckland 02    87.10596     11.34609
4   Auckland 03    87.82895     11.29961
5   Auckland 04    88.20395     11.15151
6   Auckland 05    88.07237     11.06513
7   Auckland 06    88.80921     10.96934
8   Auckland 07    88.46053     10.96316
9   Auckland 08    87.50658     11.59500
10  Auckland 09    85.03947     12.58395
11  Auckland 10    79.73684     13.80546
12  Auckland 11    75.23684     14.79230
13  Auckland 12    73.01974     15.25612
14  Auckland 13    71.24837     15.50320
15  Auckland 14    69.88889     15.62948
16  Auckland 15    70.81699     15.51739
17  Auckland 16    71.79739     15.14314
18  Auckland 17    74.93464     14.30928
19  Auckland 18    79.57516     13.50771
20  Auckland 19    81.19608     13.03699
21  Auckland 20    82.69281     12.56595
22  Auckland 21    84.43791     12.28150
23  Auckland 22    85.07843     12.05542
24  Auckland 23    85.75163     11.82458
25  Wellington 00    87.00000     11.62608
26  Wellington 01    86.87500     11.52487
27  Wellington 02    87.10596     11.34609
..  Wellington 03    87.82895     11.29961
..  Wellington 04    88.20395     11.15151
..  Wellington 05    88.07237     11.06513
..  Wellington 06    88.80921     10.96934
..  Wellington 07    88.46053     10.96316
..  Wellington 08    87.50658     11.59500
..  Wellington 09    85.03947     12.58395
..  Wellington 10    79.73684     13.80546
..  Wellington 11    75.23684     14.79230
..  Wellington 12    73.01974     15.25612
..  Wellington 13    71.24837     15.50320
..  Wellington 14    69.88889     15.62948
..  Wellington 15    70.81699     15.51739
..  Wellington 16    71.79739     15.14314
..  Wellington 17    74.93464     14.30928
..  Wellington 18    79.57516     13.50771
..  Wellington 19    81.19608     13.03699
..  Wellington 20    82.69281     12.56595
..  Wellington 21    84.43791     12.28150
..  Wellington 22    85.07843     12.05542
..  Wellington 23    85.75163     11.82458
```

For each unique device_id in the top data.table, I need to do a regression of the mean_t against the outdoor_temp for the matching city as given in the second data.table. Crucially, some of the items need to use the Wellington weather set, and some the Auckland set. ACtually in the full set there cold be dozens of locations. My thinking is that if I can use rbind to output a format something like:

h    2C7985 2C7985_outdoor   2C797D 2C797D_outdoor ...
0
1
2
...
23

where the _outdoor is the data from the matching city. Then I can do a regression test by searching for each heading that doesn't contain _outdoor and compare it to the corresponding column that does... Here's the code for the case where there is only one city:

```
table_4 <- c()

# for each column (except h and "Auckland")
for (i in names(reg_data)[!(names(reg_data) %in% c("h", "Auckland"))]) {
  
  # make a line of linear model comparing the column to the weather.
  model <- lm(reg_data[[i]] ~ Auckland, data = reg_data)
  
  # bind this new chunk of model action to the table thingy. 
  table_4 <- rbind(table_4_1_1, dust(model) %>% as.tibble())
}
```

It's a tricky one, but I reckon there's an R guru out there willing to help this poor old embedded C coder out!

```
> dput(reg_data[1:48, ])
structure(list(device_id = c("2C7970", "2C7970", "2C7970", "2C7970", 
"2C7970", "2C7970", "2C7970", "2C7970", "2C7970", "2C7970", "2C7970", 
"2C7970", "2C7970", "2C7970", "2C7970", "2C7970", "2C7970", "2C7970", 
"2C7970", "2C7970", "2C7970", "2C7970", "2C7970", "2C7970", "2C797D", 
"2C797D", "2C797D", "2C797D", "2C797D", "2C797D", "2C797D", "2C797D", 
"2C797D", "2C797D", "2C797D", "2C797D", "2C797D", "2C797D", "2C797D", 
"2C797D", "2C797D", "2C797D", "2C797D", "2C797D", "2C797D", "2C797D", 
"2C797D", "2C797D"), h = c("00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", 
"06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "00", "01", "02", "03", 
"04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"), city = c("Auckland", 
"Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", 
"Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", 
"Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", 
"Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", 
"Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", 
"Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", 
"Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", 
"Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland"), 
    mean_t = c(18.6050736497545, 18.5626644736842, 18.4610927152318, 
    18.3891447368421, 18.2909539473684, 18.2861842105263, 18.287417218543, 
    18.2872516556291, 18.3468543046358, 18.5296540362438, 18.7825657894737, 
    19.0549342105263, 19.1362745098039, 19.3024509803922, 19.491339869281, 
    19.4937908496732, 19.4274509803922, 19.3047385620915, 19.2575163398693, 
    19.1503267973856, 19.0248366013072, 18.8842105263158, 18.7924342105263, 
    18.7026315789474, 16.3553633217993, 16.1324137931034, 15.9129310344828, 
    15.6494827586207, 15.3448275862069, 15.1929310344828, 15.1694827586207, 
    15.2339655172414, 15.6901724137931, 16.1834482758621, 16.6058620689655, 
    16.8025862068966, 16.9284246575342, 17.3171232876712, 17.573756432247, 
    17.6306896551724, 17.7255172413793, 17.6962068965517, 17.5627586206897, 
    17.4553448275862, 17.2977586206897, 17.0729636048527, 16.8368055555556, 
    16.6506944444444)), row.names = c(NA, -48L), groups = structure(list(
    device_id = c("2C7970", "2C797D"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:24, 25:48), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

 dput(Hourly_Weather)
structure(list(city_name = c("Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", 
"Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", 
"Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", 
"Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland", 
"Auckland", "Auckland", "Auckland"), h = c("00", "01", "02", 
"03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"), 
    outdoor_hum = c(87, 86.875, 87.1059602649007, 87.8289473684211, 
    88.2039473684211, 88.0723684210526, 88.8092105263158, 88.4605263157895, 
    87.5065789473684, 85.0394736842105, 79.7368421052632, 75.2368421052632, 
    73.0197368421053, 71.2483660130719, 69.8888888888889, 70.8169934640523, 
    71.797385620915, 74.9346405228758, 79.5751633986928, 81.1960784313726, 
    82.6928104575163, 84.437908496732, 85.078431372549, 85.7516339869281
    ), outdoor_temp = c(11.6260784313725, 11.5248684210526, 11.3460927152318, 
    11.2996052631579, 11.1515131578947, 11.0651315789474, 10.9693421052632, 
    10.9631578947368, 11.595, 12.5839473684211, 13.8054605263158, 
    14.7923026315789, 15.2561184210526, 15.5032026143791, 15.629477124183, 
    15.517385620915, 15.143137254902, 14.3092810457516, 13.5077124183007, 
    13.0369934640523, 12.5659477124183, 12.2815032679739, 12.0554248366013, 
    11.8245751633987)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), groups = structure(list(
    city_name = "Auckland", .rows = structure(list(1:24), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Your data has different columns do it doesn't make sense to rbind (row bind) the data. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Use a smaller number of rows in the example to make things more clear exactly what you need to have happen.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick. I've just added some bits of the data frame with dput which I found at your link. Is that usable. I've simplified it to just 2 devices that happen to be in the same city, but of course theidea is that it will work for multipe cities.

Comment: Have you tried `merge(reg_data, weather, by.x = c('city', 'h') , by.y = c('city_name', 'h'))` ?

Comment: @RonakShah that certainly works to join the sets together. The goal is to run the regression between each device_id and the corresponding outdoor data set. How does this data transform get us there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyverse` way to do this would be to fit a linear regression model for each `device_id`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(pixiedust)

inner_join(reg_data, weather, by = c('city' = 'city_name', 'h')) %>%
  group_by(device_id) %>%
  summarise(model = list(lm(mean_t ~ outdoor_temp)), 
            data = purrr::map(model, ~dust(.x) %>% as.tibble)) %>%
  unnest(data) %>%
  select(-model)

#  device_id term         estimate std.error statistic p.value
#  <chr>     <chr>        <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>  
#1 2C7970    (Intercept)  15.861   0.284     55.831    0      
#2 2C7970    outdoor_temp 0.23     0.022     10.526    0      
#3 2C797D    (Intercept)  11.146   0.85      13.112    0      
#4 2C797D    outdoor_temp 0.422    0.065     6.449     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. I found a book called R for Data Science online and it answered my question. I built on the suggestion from @Ronak Shah, so thanks very much for that. Hope this is useful for others.

```
# filter down to the necessary stuff
reg_data <-
  prep_data %>%
  select(device_id, h, city, mean_t) %>%
  filter(as.integer(h) %in% c(20:23, 0:7))


# don't worry about extra day time hours in Hourly Weather NA ignored later.
merged <- merge(reg_data, Hourly_Weather, by.x = c('city', 'h') , by.y = c('city_name', 'h'))

new_table <- c()

# get unique list of device_ids
deviceList <- 
  prep_data %>%
  select(device_id) %>% 
  unique() %>%
  unlist() %>% 
  unname()

for (dev in deviceList) {
  subset <- merged %>% 
    filter(device_id == dev)
    model <- lm(mean_t ~ outdoor_temp, data = subset, na.action=na.exclude)
    new_table <- rbind(new_table, dust(model) %>% as.tibble())
}
```